# How possible change format date in for-each

Tags: bi-publisher

Is it possible to change date format in for-each? (for rtf template).

- As example i have:
  account Z4444444 date 09/11/2020 account Z5555555 date 08/28/2020
- I need:
  account Z4444444 date 11/09/2020 account Z5555555 date 28/08/2020

I try use code with variable

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'CCD4', EffectiveDate)?> 

<?for-each@inlines:FinsBillingAccounts?><?Account?> <?xdoxslt: right(xdoxslt: left(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'CCD4'),5),2)?>/<?xdoxslt:left(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'CCD4'),2)?>/<?xdoxslt: right(xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'CCD4'),4)?> 
 <?end for-each?>
```

But as result I have problem with date (date don't work with for each). For every account I have only first date:

- Z4444444 11/09/2020  Z5555555  11/09/2020

my xml (example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListofIO>
<FinsBillingAccounts>
<Account>Z4444444</Account>
<EffectiveDate>09/11/2020</EffectiveDate>
</FinsBillingAccounts>
<FinsBillingAccounts>
<Account>Z5555555</Account>
<EffectiveDate>08/28/2020</EffectiveDate>
</FinsBillingAccounts>
<Login>L</Login>
</ListAccountsNew>
</ListofIO>
```

UPD: I found second option and solution :

```
<?xdoxslt:format_date(EffectiveDate,'dd-MM-yyyy ','MM/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)?>

<?for-each@inlines:FinsBillingAccounts?><?Account?>  <? xdoxslt:format_date(EffectiveDate,'dd-MM-yyyy ','MM/dd/yyyy',$_XDOLOCALE,$_XDOTIMEZONE)?> year
 <?end for-each?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you store your dates in the correct format in the XML, you'll be able to use the built in date formatting.

Example Date format which should be in your XML elements for dates:

```
2015-06-24T19:54:19.000+00:00
```

If you have not already, install the BI Publisher Desktop application with Word add-in.

You should get this option once you double click an RTF data Element:
[image]

You should be able to change your date format there.

Then, if you want conditional date formatting per record, you'll need an additional element in your XML to indicate which date format to use for that record.

Example: `DATE_FORMAT`

Finally, just use simple `if` statements, which depend on that new date format element. Put the proper format into each if statement.

Example:

```
<?if:DATE_FORMAT='US'?>
<?EFFECTIVE_DATE?>  //Format this date in the RTF: M/d/yyyy
<?end if?>
<?if:DATE_FORMAT='INTERNATIONAL'?>
<?EFFECTIVE_DATE?>  //Format this date in the RTF: d/M/yyyy
<?end if?>
```

Comment: EdHayes- Thanks for you answer. I have installed BIP Desktop and try work with "Text Form Field Option" but in my situation this don't work. (Format date does not change).

Comment: You'll have to provide more details on how it's not working, and what else you have tried. If you have not corrected the date structure coming through in the XML, you wont be able to format the date on the RTF side of the process.

Comment: EdHayes3 - i can't change  xml (xml generated by external system). But i found solution which work for me. I just use <?xdoxslt:format_date(EffectiveDate,'dd-MM-yyyy ','MM/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)?>. This work in combination with <?for-each@inlines.  Thanks for your help